# Keyboard backlight on Xiaomi Notebook keeps turning off

Tags: keyboard, 18.04, brightness, backlight

Ubuntu 18.04 is installed on my Xiaomi Notebook 13".

I am having an issue with the keyboard backlight : after a few seconds without using the keyboard, the backlight of the keyboard turns off until you press any key.

How can I keep the light always on?

I can't find a setting in the BIOS nor in the setting menus.

Answer (score 2):

Most keyboard backlights are intended to work that way, turning off after a short time of not typing.

With that said, there's probably some subdirectory in `/sys/class/leds` for your keyboard backlight. Mine is `/sys/class/leds/dell::kbd_backlight`. Inside that are several control files that you can `cat` to see what they're set to. You can `echo` to them with `sudo` to change them.

With mine, `sudo bash -c 'echo 46799s > stop_timeout'` in that directory sets the backlight to stay on for half a day after pressing a key, which may not give you exactly what you want, but might be good enough.
Perhaps yours is similar or there's some other file in your keyboard backlight subdirectory that you can write to to get the effect that you want.

Comment: I went through the whole `/sys/class/` folder but couldn't find the keyboard nor anything linked to xiaomi. I guess some driver isn't working properly on linux. Thanks for your reply tho !

Comment: But first observe if any of these LEDs controls the keyboard backlight. You can use `brightnessctl -l` for that (which can be installed with `apt`).

Answer (score 0):

Restart and boot into BIOS (press F2), in bios go to power settings and change keyboard light from power saving mode to standard mode.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. There is no such option in my BIOS, maybe you updated yours recently ? If so do you have a link for the file ?